# Results of multiple queries with aggregates combined

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 seperate select statements, using aggregate functions in each. I would like to be able to take the results and combine them.

```
table_a
id int
entered_date datetime (holds utc stamp)
balance money
group_id int

table_b
id int
entered_date date
balance money
transaction_type int

query 1: 
select convert(date,entered_date), sum(balance) as earned
from table_a
where group_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
group by convert(date,entered_Date)

query 2: 
select convert(date,entered_date), sum(balance) as spent
where transaction_type = 2
group by convert(date,entered_Date)

results:
query 1:
2012-05-13, 5000
2012-05-14, 12000
...

query 2:
2012-05-13, 9000
2012-05-14, 55856
...
```

I would like to return one row for each record without using temp tables. The result set should have a date, then earned vs. spent. I have a report running using union to get the totals and that is fine, but i need to generate a result set with 1 record and a earned vs against line. Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean to include `from table_b` in query 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
;With AllDates AS
(
select convert(date,entered_date) As EnteredDate
    from table_a
    where group_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
    group by convert(date,entered_Date)
UNION
select convert(date,entered_date)
    from table_b
    where transaction_type = 2
    group by convert(date,entered_Date)
)
, AllEarned AS (
select convert(date,entered_date) AS EnteredDate, sum(balance) as Earned
    from table_a
    where group_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
    group by convert(date,entered_Date)
)
, AllSpent AS (
select convert(date,entered_date) AS EnteredDate, sum(balance) as Spent
    from table_b
    where transaction_type = 2
    group by convert(date,entered_Date)
)
SELECT
    d.EnteredDate, e.Earned, s.Spent
    FROM AllDates d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AllEarned e ON d.EnteredDate=e.EnteredDate
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AllSpent s ON d.EnteredDate=s.EnteredDate
    ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: I am getting the following errors: 
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.

Comment: are you running SQL Server 2005+ ?  I did remove the "order by" from the AllSpent CTE (which is an error), but I can't see any other syntax errors.  I don't have SQL Server to try running the code.

Comment: I am still not having any luck with the syntax. is there somewhere i can post my query so you can see what i may or may not have missed?

Comment: I am running this in both sql 2008r2 and sql 2012

Comment: It is working now, seems the issue was there was no AS in the first CTE. I took the order by out of all except the last query, and its working like a charm. Can you explain a bit to me on how CTE's differ from say running the queries seperately and then joining them with a select into to populate the temp table?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
       CASE WHEN a.a_date IS NULL THEN b.a_date ELSE a.a_date END as a_data, 
       a.earned,
       b.spent
FROM
    (select 
         convert(date,entered_date) as a_date, 
         sum(balance) as earned
    from table_a
    where group_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
    group by entered_Date) A
FULL OUTER JOIN 
   (select 
        convert(date,entered_date) as a_date, 
        sum(balance) as spent
    from table_a
    where transaction_type = 2
    group by entered_Date) B 
ON A.a_date=b.a_date
```

Or using `FULL OUTER JOIN` if there are data that don't meet both conditions. And using `CASE WHEN a.a_date IS NULL THEN b.a_date ELSE a.a_date END as a_data`

Comment: This doesn't work when some dates don't have transactions meeting both conditions.

Comment: the tables may not always have transactions meeting both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine these using logic, assuming that both are from the same table
 (the second query is missing the from statement):

```
select convert(date,entered_date),
       sum(case when group_id in (1, 2, 3, 4) then balance end) as earned,
       sum(case when transaction_type = 2 then balance end) as spend
from table_a
group by convert(date,entered_Date)
```

Comment: sorry i should have specified they are not from the same table. the first is from A the second from b

Comment: In that case, the union solution is probably the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming earned amounts are from table_a and spent amounts are from table_b,

```
; WITH a AS (
    select entered_date=convert(date,entered_date), balance as earned, 0 AS spent
    from table_a
    where group_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
    UNION ALL
    select entered_date=convert(date,entered_date), 0 AS earned, balance as spent
    from table_b
    where transaction_type = 2
)
SELECT entered_date
, earned=SUM(earned)
, spent=SUM(spent)
FROM a
GROUP BY entered_date
```